# Importing Jena to Eclipse: compile problems

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jena

I believe I've followed the instructions from https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/using_jena_with_eclipse.html: I ran mvn clean install with apparently no issues, but then when I tried to import the maven project to Eclipse, I had 271 errors, mostly pertaining to the Graph type, which didn't compile somehow.  I can't seem to find advice on how to resolve this issue anywhere.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

[image]

I first cloned the git repository and did a clean install:

git clone https://github.com/apache/jena.git
cd jena
mvn clean install

I also installed Eclipse using a flatpak (I'm using Fedora).

Then in my Eclipse workspace, I imported Jena as an existing Maven project. The build produced these errors.  I looked through them a bit, but I can't seem to identify the root of the problem.  Has anyone encountered build issues with Jena?  Any tips?

Comment: It works better if you include only java projects - not the "pom" ones (the root, jena-fuseki2, jena-dboe, jena-extras). Otherwise you can get maven artifacts included multiple times - once directly and also as subfolders of another import.

For jena-benchmarks - jena-benchmarks-jmh -- if you don't need, don't have them in Eclipse.

After a large import, you may have to find the earliest project causing problems and do a Eclipse refresh on it. You can see the build order from maven.